# Dell XPS 8940 desktop boot problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, usb, dell

I just bought a new Dell XPS 8940 with Nvidia GTX 1660 Super Graphics card and Win 10 preinstalled.  I wanted to install Ubuntu Studio 20.04 on it and run dual boot with Win10.  I used UNetBootin to create a live USB of Ubuntu Studio ISO.  I downloaded both the Ubuntu Studio ISO and UNetBootin in Win10 to my downloads folder and created the bootable Ubuntu USB. Ubuntu Studio boots and runs fine off the USB stick on another computer.  However, I can no longer boot into the new Dell XPS 8940 in Win10.  I don't see a boot screen or anything, and no video signal appears from either the HDMI or Displayport from either the GTX 1660 card or the built in graphics ports.  Did the USB install do something to my Bios settings and if so how do I fix, given the fact I can't see video output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Two Issues: And it sounds like you will need to do Reference 2B and 2A BEFORE you can fix the problem

1:
A "High-severity security bugs found in Nvidia drivers" in both
the Windows and the Linux Drivers.

There was a problem with the drivers for the Nvidia GTX 1660 Super Graphics card and an updated version was released last week.

But it is worse than that. A "High-severity security bugs found in Nvidia drivers" and after I read the article about it, I updated mine.
In Reference:
https://www.techradar.com/news/nvidia-warns-gamers-to-update-their-gpu-drivers-right-now-due-to-severe-security-problems

Issue Two
Part A the problem
Part B Fix with Boot Live Windows Tools:

2A:
Overview
Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST) is a solution built into a range of Intel chipsets. On platforms that have RST support built and enabled in the computer’s BIOS, it allows users to group and manage multiple hard disks as single volumes. This functionality is known as the Redundant Array of Independent Disks (RAID).

In some usage scenarios, RAID offers various advantages over the use of several disks independently. RAID offers multiple configurations - levels - which focus on performance and redundancy.

The directions for

"Changing the storage controller protocol from RST to Advanced Host Controller Interface (AHCI)."

And more is posted

In Reference:
https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

2B:
Fix with Boot Live Windows Tools

Search terms used
"Boot Live Windows 10 repair distros 2021 Hirens"

The following looks like an excellent reference {from the search I did}>

5 Bootable Windows PE ISO To Boot, Recover And Repair Windows
Posted January 1, 2021
https://www.geckoandfly.com/32030/bootable-windows-pe-recovery-repair/